# Better (or different) proof of Marginal PDF?

Tags: probability-theory

I am taking a probability course and the book provides the following proof for the Marginal PDF of a variable (assume 2 variables for ease).

$f_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy $  -- Marginal PDF

Proof:

$F_X(x) = P[X \le x] = \int_{-\infty}^x[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_x(x,y)dy]du $

Differentiate both sides and you obtain the first equation.

Does anyone have a better proof?!  - I haven't found a better/different online yet.

Comment: I am sure that your book does not give the proof that you have given above. What is $u$ on the right side?  Since the inner integral does not involve $u$ and thus can be treated as a constant when integrating with respect to $u$, why does the integral $\int_{-\infty}^x du$ converge? Please edit your question to state what your book _does_ give as the proof. Also, tell is the definition of the pdf of $X$ that you are using.

Comment: I copied this DIRECTLY out of the book. Probability and Stochastic Processes by Yates and Goodman. $du$ is a dummy variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $X$ has a probability density function $f_X$ if and only if $f$ is measurable, $f_X(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, and
$$
P(X\in A)=\int_A f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx,\quad A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),
$$
where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, we just have to check that $f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$ satisfies these three properties. That $f_X$ is measurable and non-negative follows from the fact that $f_{X,Y}$ is measurable and non-negative. Moreover, if $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ we have (note we are using Tonelli/Fubini's theorem)

$$
\begin{align}
P(X\in A)&=P((X,Y)\in A\times \mathbb{R})=\int_{A\times \mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_A\left\{\int_\mathbb{R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\right\}\,\mathrm dx=\int_A f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx,
\end{align}
$$
and hence $f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$ is the probability density function of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is more or less the same proof. I'll accept it since no one has given a better answer and this is much more formal than my book (a book for engineers - that really was EXACTLY the proof given in the book)